# Scala For Comprehension with Filter

Tags: scala

I am using Scala's for comprehension to produce a modified `facetFilter`. If a value in `facetFilter` doesn't exist in `allFacets`, it should be filtered out. Currently, the `newFacetFilter` doesn't filter at all.

```
val allFacets = Map(
  "band_material" -> Map("Rubber" -> 11),
  "dial_color" -> Map("Ivory" -> 68, "Salmon"-> 3))


val facetFilter =
  Map("band_material" -> List("Yellow Gold Plated", "Rubber"),
    "dial_color" -> List("Ivory"))

val newFacetFilter =
  for {
    (k,v) <- allFacets
    (facetName, facetArr) <- facetFilter
    aFacet <- facetArr
    if k != facetName || !v.contains(aFacet)
  } yield (facetName -> facetArr)
```

Current Output of `newFacetFilter`:

```
Map("band_material" -> List("Yellow Gold Plated", "Rubber"), "dial_color" -> List("Ivory"))
```

Expected Output of `newFacetFilter`:

```
Map("band_material" -> List("Rubber"), "dial_color" -> List("Ivory"))
```

[See this fiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/Xt2xpW2/9)

Comment: You should use case classes, not maps of strings. It would make your code a lot easier to read and comprehend.

Comment: Ok, def in the pipeline

Comment: I updated the expected output

Comment: Are you sure that's the expected output? `Rubber` does appear and `Ivory` does not. If that is what you want, please explain the desired logic.

Comment: I have updated code sample. I want Rubber and Ivory to appear, sans "Yellow Gold"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
val newFacetFilter = 
  for ((k,vs) <- facetFilter) 
  yield (k, vs filter allFacets(k).contains)
```

Output:

```
Map(band_material -> List(Rubber), dial_color -> List(Ivory))
```

Comment: Really elegant solution! Why did my solution not work?

Comment: @AvremelKaminetzky I'm not sure why it doesn't work, there are just too many levels of nested iterations. You need to iterate through `facetFilter` only once, and filter out those values that are also contained in `allFacets` for the corresponding key. That's one iteration. Three nested loops are just too much.

Answer (score 1):

OK, if we are done with edits, I think this is what you want...

```
val allFacets = Map(
  "band_material" -> Map(
    "Rubber" -> 11
  ),
  "dial_color" -> Map(
    "Ivory" -> 68,
    "Salmon"-> 3
  )
)

val facetFilter = Map(
  "band_material" -> List("Yellow Gold Plated", "Rubber"),
  "dial_color" -> List("Ivory"),
  "case_material" -> List(),
  "movement" -> List(),
  "price_range" -> List(),
  "gender" -> List()
)

val newFacetFilter = for {
  (facetName, facetArr) <- facetFilter
  (k,v) <- allFacets
  if k == facetName
} yield (facetName, facetArr intersect v.keys.toList)
```

We simply iterate both maps and when we have the same keys, we `intersect` the two lists.

Edit: There is a more efficient way, using the `Map`'s `get` function instead of just iterating everything and ignoring non-matches.

```
val newFacetFilter = facetFilter.flatMap {
  case (n, fs) => 
    allFacets.get(n).map(n -> _.keys.toList.intersect(fs))
}
```

So we take each facetFilter entry (`(n, fs)`), check `allFacets` for `n`, then intersect the optional result with our list `fs`. If `n` did not exist, we propagate `None` and it is flattened out by `flatMap`.

Comment: Iterating through `allFacets`, generating combinations with all keys, then using only the combinations where `k == facetName`? That seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: Well it is following the style he was looking for. I will add a more efficient method to the answer.